# How can I prevent django from claiming localhost port 80 via httpd after I've removed my project?

Tags: django, macos, apache, sudo, httpd.conf

My problem is that my localhost port 80 is taken by an auto-reloading Django proc that I no longer need and I cannot kill the Django proc(s) because they auto-reload upon being killed.

I did Django a while ago for an interview assignment so it's not trivial to get back into that and manage it that way.  Is there a way simply on macos to prevent this process from coming back?  I've tried using `launchctl` but it's unclear which item would be facilitating the auto-reloading.

I have 2 mystery django process that get auto-reloaded whenever I kill it with `sudo kill {PID}`.  i.e. I kill the procs, I check to make sure port 80 is not being used anymore with `sudo lsof -i :80`, and it shows 2 new procs that have auto-reloaded.

I am hoping to do anything at all so that when I run `sudo lsof -i :80` I get no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this command to kill the process and not auto reload

[Update] This command works for linux only

`fuser -k 80/tcp`

In this case, apache had to be stopped using
`sudo apachectl stop` or `sudo httpd -k stop`

Comment: When I try that, it gives me:

ryan@Ryans-MacBook-Pro ~ % fuser -k 80/tcp
Unknown option: k
fuser: [-cfu] file ...
 -c file is treated as mount point
 -f the report is only for the named files
 -u print username of pid in parenthesis

Comment: Oh my bad. This was for linux. The mac `fuser` does not have -k option. Let me see if there is another way.

Comment: What does it show when you run `sudo lsof -i :80` can you add that in the question? 
Also do you remember what was the command that you used to run Django?

Comment: COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   2862 root    4u  IPv6 0x2404f6f518619b3      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   2867 _www    4u  IPv6 0x2404f6f518619b3      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

Comment: The 2 processes are being repeated by httpd.  I could even uninstall httpd if that's a thing.  Just need any way at all for this to stop re-appearing.

Comment: Did you use apache at the time? If so can you do this command and check 
`sudo httpd -k stop` or if you used apache then try `sudo apachectl stop`

Comment: That worked Arun!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I have updated my answer to include this. Please accept it if it helped you. Thank you